# Mouse wheel doesn't scroll in emacs 23.4.1 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: emacs, mouse-scroll

Scrolling with the mouse wheel doesn't work for me in emacs.  When I try, I get the messages:

```
mouse-4 [[or mouse-5]] is undefined
```

I tried M-x mouse-wheel-mode, but get the error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: mouse-wheel-mode
```

---

Possibly useful information:

- I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04, dual-booted with Windows 8 on my
  laptop.
- I installed **emacs** using `apt-get install emacs`, which pulled version
  23.4.1
- I'm a fairly comfortable Linux user, but I have very little system
  management experience so it's entirely possible I'm missing something
  obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Have you loaded library `mwheel.el[c]`, where `mouse-wheel-mode` is defined?

1. Make sure the library is in your `load-path`:

   (add-to-list 'load-path "/your/path/to/dir/where/mwheel.el/is/located/")
2. Then load it:

   (require 'mwheel)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I missed it when you replied.  I actually fixed the problem myself recently.  Only root had access to my .emacs.d directory; adding full access for everyone made emacs start behaving.

Answer (score 0):

Dan hit it with the perms on .emacs.d - the current emacs package installer assigns root:root ownership and no user perms on that (empty) directory. Changing the ownership fixes the scroll wheel problem. I'd call that permissions issue a bug. I'd vote up the answer but it's in a comment - thanks, Dan!